# CSS media query OR operator (,) not working as expected

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a media query for a website which depends on the width of the viewing window:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
...
}
```

This works perfectly.

I found that there was an issue with  the site menu being cut off on certain devices because the height of the viewing window was not taken into account in the above statement, so I adjusted the statement accordingly *(the menu is usually vertical but with the small screen or small height the menu should be changed to being horizontal)* :

```
@media (max-width: 600px),  (max-height: 400px){
...
}
```

However this does not work, the max-width value works but if I resize my window (Firefox and Chrome) to a letterbox size (`<400px`) then it doesn't run the corresponding `height` rules contained in the media query.

I have also played with variations such as :

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px), all and (max-height: 400px){
...
}
```

But with no success.

I have read various articles about CSS height but I can't see why my rules above are not applying? Any answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be solved when applying **the opposite** query to all other media query cases:

such as all OTHER media queries need to have a `and (min-height: 401px)` appended to each of their cases, so they do not overwrite the case above.

cheers

Answer (score 3):

Tried

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) and (max-height: 400px) {
    body {
        background:#000;
    }
}
```

and worked fine!

**UPDATE**: the OR worked too http://jsfiddle.net/noj3u3xn/

```css
@media (max-width: 600px), (max-height: 300px) {
    body {
        background:#000;
    }
}
```

Maybe you can share more of your css?

Comment: the `and` works fine, but it seems the OR media operator (`,`) seems to be not working correctly.

Comment: updated my answer. Maybe the problem is not in the query but the css in it. Can you share some more css?

Comment: @idioteque thanks for the update. I found that what I think has happening was that other media queries where coming into play because they where set via the width, so if the height was the correct height for the shown query, but the width fired off another query, the other query would overwrite this query. I have now clarified my code in my CSS file and fixed the issue. Cheers for the help. +1.